# Customer does not have linked source with id

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I keep getting the following error when viewing stripe test trasactions:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Customer cus_9tW8Cf0Xvm9lRv does not have a linked source with ID tok_19Zj5rAANnhOmz4ex3ri2jtW.",
    "param": "source",
    "code": "missing"
  }
}
```

my swift code to call the api is as follows:

```
    @IBAction func payButtonWasPressed() {
        stripeCard = STPCardParams()

        let expirationDate = self.cardExpiryTextField.text!.components(separatedBy: "/")
        let expMonth = UInt(expirationDate[0])
        let expYear = UInt(expirationDate[1])

        stripeCard.number = self.cardNumberTextField.text
        stripeCard.cvc = self.cardCVVTextField.text
        stripeCard.expMonth = expMonth!
        stripeCard.expYear = expYear!

        STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: stripeCard, completion: { (token, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                self.handleError(error! as NSError)
                return
            } 

            self.chargeUsingToken(token!)
        })
    }

    func handleError(_ error: NSError) {
        UIAlertView(title: "Please Try Again",
                    message: error.localizedDescription,
                    delegate: nil,
                    cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()

    }

    func chargeUsingToken(_ token: STPToken) {

        let URL = "https://splitterstripeserver.herokuapp.com/charge"
        let params = ["source": token.tokenId,
                      "stripe_token": token.tokenId,
                      "amount": total] as [String : Any]

        let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
        manager.post(URL, parameters: params, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in

            if let response = responseObject as? [String: String] {
                UIAlertView(title: response["status"],
                    message: response["message"],
                    delegate: nil,
                    cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
            }

        }) { (operation, error) -> Void in
            self.handleError(error as NSError)
        }
    }
```

and I am using the example backend found on the [stripe github](https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend)

On my app I get a pop-up saying Request failed: payment required (402). I have tried a lot of different things but can't seem to get successful response. I cant see what im doing wrong and need a fresh pair of eyes. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you create the card token with [Stripe Checkout](http://zcheck) or [Stripe.js](http://zjs), you send it to your server where you use it to create a customer via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer). That card becomes "saved" with that customer and you can then charge it in the future. If you want to add another card to the same customer you would use the Create Card [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card) to pass the new token and add that card.

When you create a [charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge), you pass the customer id (cus_XXX) in the `customer` parameter to charge the default card. If you want to charge a specific card, you would pass the card id (card_YYY) in the `source` parameter along with the customer.

At the moment, you are trying to pass a customer id and a card token which is not supported. You'll need to save that card on the customer first and then pass the new card id in the `source` parameter as mentioned above.

Comment: This seems like bad design. Not all customers will want their card details saved with a, let's be frank, less known payment platform. -- It seems reasonable that a one-off token should be chargeable linked to a customer.

Comment: @Adambean I would disagree here. You can always charge a one-time token and then attach the Charge to a customer afterwards: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/update#update_charge-customer

Comment: if that's allowed why not just allow the charge to be associated with the customer at the time of creation? That would cut the transaction requirement count from 2 to 1. -- I can't think of a good reason to allow this after the charge has happened but not during.